# Theme Fusion .css modification for [featured_products_slider] to center images

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using a Theme Fusion theme for my wordpress site. I need to center the images in the [featured_products_slider]. What .css modification do I need to use?

Comment: It seems to be aligned center on the image that I'm watching by the link you gave us

Comment: Oooh I get it, lol. just add `align="center"` on the html page like this:
 `<div class="products-slider es-carousel" align="center">` this should work but if not send me the link of the website so I can see more precisely what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks Chun. The slider is aligned center but the images within it are not. Would this code help with that issue? If not I can make the page live and send a link. Thanks again.

Comment: yeah make it live so I can help you better that way.

Comment: The site is: http://www.hothothot.com/shop/

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by adding the following CSS:

```
.products-slider li img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: none;
}
```

Although you should search for the `.products-slider li img` class and delete the float style and add these margin left and right where that class exists on your CSS file. but this will  do the work.